# Quickest way to find max or min of 4 integers?

Tags: c, sorting

I have four parameters, each an integer and I want to find the smallest. What is the quickest and/or simplest way to do it? I can probably do a bubble sort but it seems overkill.

Comment: Suggest making title, body and answer selection consistent.  The title ask for "quick and min/max of fixed array size".  The body asks for "quick/simple and min of fixed array size".  These are similar  as quick (in processor speed) and simple (coding complexity) can readily differ.  The selected answer does well answer "simple and min/max of variable array size".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're only look for the largest and/or smallest, traverse the full list, keeping track of the smallest and largest value you've seen so far.  No need to search.

For example:

```
void print_min_max(int list[], int len)
{
    int max = INT_MIN, min = INT_MAX;
    int i;

    for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
        if (list[i] < min) min = list[i];
        if (list[i] > max) max = list[i];
    }
    printf("min=%d, max=%d\n", min, max);
}
```

Comment: fine, i see it @dbush

Answer (score 10):

```
int min(int a, int b){
    return a<b?a:b;
}
```

call as:

```
min(min(a,b),min(c,d))
```

Answer (score 3):

*Quickest way...*
The following method has not been compared against other methods for speed, but if you would like to find min or max without using the ternary operator (to avoid the branch) or looping, you can define these functions:

```
int min(int x,int y) 
{
    return y ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); // min(x, y)
}
int max(int x,int y) 
{
    return x ^ ((x ^ y) & -(x < y)); // max(x, y)
}

int main() 
{

  int minn, maxx;

  //evaluating pairs
  minn = min(3,6);
  maxx = max(3,6);

  //evaluating multiple values:
  minn = min(9,min(8,min(2,5)));//expand as needed
  maxx = max(9,max(8,max(2,5)));

  return 0;
}
```

*Note on efficiency*: Regarding ternary operator methods, I believe compiler optimizations on modern compilers will likely eliminate branching inherent with the ternary operator, making usage of that technique a non-issue (with regards to speed anyway).

Answer (score 2):

```
int FindMin(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    int min1 = (a>b)?b:a;
    int min2 = (c>d)?d:c;
    return (min1>min2)?min2:min1;
}
```